# Oracle Query in .NET Multiple Statements Without BEGIN END?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, ado.net

I'm trying to do a chain of queries that rely on one another in ADO.NET. I cannot post the queries as the table structure is proprietary, but what I need to know is whether it's possible to run many queries in a single call to the database without wrapping them in a BEGIN/END call and without using a stored procedure?

For example:

My queries are basically the following:

```
Insert into temp table
Insert into temp table2
Select * from temp table2
```

However, the problem I run into is that since they are separate queries as strings, I get an `INVALID CHARACTER` error if I use semi-colons to separate them, and I've read online that to fix this I need to use a BEGIN END statement. Great, but as soon as I use a BEGIN-END statement I get the error:

```
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Which I also find is a result of using PL/SQL. I've attempted to put an INTO statement into the query, but it would change the results, and the task I have been given is to run this query while changing as little as possible.

Can I run the above pattern of queries without a BEGIN-END statement? Is there another technique to use? I'm no Oracle expert and have searched in vain for an answer.

Possible relevant code:

Where I run the queries. (Note, I tried to chain the requests and run them in a single connection, no luck.)

```
DataSet dsReturn = new DataSet();
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(strConnection))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        OracleDataAdapter oraDA = new OracleDataAdapter(strSQL, conn);
        oraDA.Fill(dsReturn);
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         _strError = e.Message;

    }
    finally
    {
         conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Thanks!